# Scraping Job Descriptions off of LinkedIn

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've created a python script that uses Selenium's library to scrape:

1. Job Titles
2. Company Name
3. Location of Job
4. Job Description (which I need help getting!), off of LinkedIn jobs search section.

I've created a for loop to iterate over the (25) jobs to pull out the description of each job using the same class name each description uses. I've been able to successfully pull out (1) description, but haven't been able to scrape out the other descriptions of the remaining (24) jobs. I'm assuming its the loops incapability to parse through each section, however if its able to pull out (1) description successfully, why aren't the other descriptions coming up?

```html
import pandas as pd 
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# This will open a new Chrome page to test specified url on (for scraping)
browser=webdriver.Chrome("My Chrome Path")
browser.get("https://www.linkedin.com")

# Requires user to enter username and password
username=browser.find_element_by_id("session_key")
username.send_keys("ENTER USERNAME")
password=browser.find_element_by_id("session_password")
password.send_keys("ENTER PASSWORD")

# Once username and password are entered, this will automatically click the submit button to login into LinkedIn
login_button=browser.find_element_by_class_name("sign-in-form__submit-button")
login_button.click()

# This is the URL to test the jobs I want to scrape from
browser.get("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=software%20developer")

# This will scrape and display (25) job titles from page (1)
job_title=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("job-card-list__title")
company_title=[]
for i in job_title:
    company_title.append(i.text)
print(company_title)
print()
print(len(company_title))


# This will scrape and display (25) company names from page (1) - correspondent to company_title above
job_company=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("job-card-container__company-name")
company_name=[]
for i in job_company:
    company_name.append(i.text)  
print(company_name)
print()
print(len(company_name))



# This will scrape and display (25) location names from page (1) - correspondent to company_title and company_name above
job_location=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("job-card-container__metadata-item")
location_name=[]
for i in job_location:
    location_name.append(i.text)  
print(location_name)
print()
print(len(location_name))

# At this point, I am trying to iterate over each of the (25) jobs to pull out the description. I've successfully been able to pull out (1) description, but haven't been able to pull out the other descriptions of the remaining (24) jobs. 
job_description=browser.find_elements_by_class_name('jobs-search__right-rail')
description_name = []
for i in job_description:
    description_name.append(i.text)
print(description_name)
print()
print(len(description_name))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has to do with how the pages are loaded.
Every time you click a new Job container, it sends a different GET request to the server.

```
This link, by default, has the first job selected.    
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=software%20developer

When you click another page, it changes the job id. 
Example: 
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=2512009247&keywords=software%20developer
```

So you can either emulate a click on the container or change the currentJobId by scraping the id from the page and reloading the page with the new link.

```
# Example of scraping the currentJobId for each item.
job_containers = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('job-card-container relative job-card-list job-card-container--clickable job-card-list--underline-title-on-hover jobs-search-results-list__list-item--active jobs-search-two-pane__job-card-container--viewport-tracking-0')
job_ids = []
for job_container in job_containers:
    job_ids.append(job_container.get_attribute("data-job-id"))
```

Function to grab the descriptions

```
def get_descriptions(browser, job_ids):
    job_descriptions = []
    for job_id in job_ids:
        browser.get(f'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId={job_id}&keywords=software%20developer')
        job_description = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('jobs-search__right-rail')[0].text
        job_descriptions.append(job_description)

    return job_descriptions
```

Comment: Thanks @Steven Posterick. Will I have to use this every time the job ID changes? Also, would you know how to match the IDs to the updated link?

Comment: @WeeklyButterfly34
Not sure how often the job ID changes, but I would query the description right after I retrieved the job ids.
I've edited my answer to show an example of how to have it grab the descriptions with the job id.

Comment: I appreciate the update and help here. I've gotten the IDs to populate into the LinkedIn link where it says {job_id}. At this point, I'm wondering how I can view the the descriptions assuming that all it is all stored in job_descriptions array declared inside of the get_descriptions function.

Comment: It is returned from the method, so to get the array of job_descriptions you would just do like:
job_descriptions = get_descriptions(browser, job_ids)
Then just loop through the array.

Comment: I just looped the get_descriptions function. After the return job_description statement I simply said: print(job_description) to get all the text content. Thank you @Steven Posterick